# Trouble with spray-json-shapeless sealed trait formatters

Tags: scala, spray, shapeless, spray-json

This questions is specific to using [spray-json-shapeless](https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless).
I'm trying to do something similar (at least from what I see) to the very first unit test in the [scalatests for sjs](https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless/blob/master/src/test/scala/fommil/sjs/FamilyFormatsSpec.scala). According to the tests, a sealed trait `SimpleTrait` and its implementations are defined in a package and formatter are "implemented" in another package. I don't actually see a formatter for SimpleTrait just the line
`implicit val SimpleTraitFormat: RootJsonFormat[SimpleTrait] = cachedImplicit`

which leads me to believe that the actual implicit formatter is coming from implicit scope. From what I understand thats what spray-json-shapeless offers, a default json marshaller for sealed traits and their implementations.

I tried to do something similar but my unit test complains that it can't find the JsonFormat for my type.

In package `core` I define my domain data.

```
package core

sealed trait ModuleInfo
case class SerialNumber( moduleSerial: String ) extends ModuleInfo
case class ColorCalibration( calibrationR: Double,
                             calibrationG: Double,
                             calibrationB: Double ) extends ModuleInfo
case class LensDistortion( distortionX: Double,
                           distortionY: Double,
                           distortionD: Double ) extends ModuleInfo
```

In package `api` I define the beginnings of my formatter object

```
package api

import fommil.sjs._
import spray.json._
import shapeless._

object Formatters extends DefaultJsonProtocol with FamilyFormats {
  import core._
  implicit val ModuleInfoFormat: RootJsonFormat[ ModuleInfo ] = cachedImplicit
}
```

I then tried writing a unit test in the `api` package (no actual test, just a println to see if it compiles and finds the necessary implicit).

```
package api

import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FlatSpecLike}
import spray.json._
/**
  * Created by kartik on 6/30/16.
  */
class FormatterSpec extends FlatSpecLike with Matchers {

  "A Serial Number" should  "serialize to json" in {
    import core._
    import Formatters._

    println( SerialNumber( "SomeSerial" ).toJson )
  }
}
```

This results in a compiler error with it saying

> Error:(22, 65) Could not find an implicit value of type
>   spray.json.RootJsonFormat[core.ModuleInfo] to cache   implicit val
>   ModuleInfoFormat: RootJsonFormat[ ModuleInfo ] = cachedImplicit

Is my understanding wrong? Should be providing an actual JsonFormatter for ModuleInfo? Where does `SimpleTrait` get its formatter from ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would get more attention with a `scala` tag.